# Calculate percent of big numbers

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate the percent from 8000000 of 17000. The result should be 0.2125 but I'm getting always 0.0

My code

```
double result = 17000/8000000*100;
```

Comment: You're using int division because all your operands are int literals.

Comment: adding .0 at the end of 17000 or 8000000 or cast one of them to double resolve the problem.

`double result = 17000 / 8000000.0 * 100`